# PsychoPy - If user doesn’t press anything, automatic assignment for key to “left” key

Tags: python, psychopy

I am currently designing an experiment where the user has to press either “left” or “right” on a screen sequence which would be used in a later screen input.

Window 1:

```
Do you think that A or B will happen?
A: press left arrow key
B: press right arrow key
```

Window 2 has a code behind it something of the sort from below in order for variables to be output in the backend for future analysis.

```
if(‘left’ in keyDecisionResponse.keys):
something to happen
elif(‘right’ in keyDecisionResponse.keys):
something else to happen
```

However, if the user doesn’t press anything (which could happen if the user is not paying attention), I receive the error:
TypeError: argument of type ‘NoneType’ is not iterable

Experiment ended.
Therefore, I would like to automatically assign ‘left’ to ‘None’ in Window 1, something of the sort:

```
if (‘None’ in keyDecisionResponse.keys):
keyDecisionResponse.keys = ‘left’
```

It does not work. Also, I tried several things, but none of them worked.

Can you please help?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you share a working piece of code that explains what behaviour you're seeing and an explanation of what you want/expect to happen instead? You said you "tried several things" - perhaps share the one you were most surprised about not working.

Comment: Your qoutes are not valid in python, the brackets are redundant, you need at least one indented statement to form a valid `if` statement or `elif` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `keyDecisionResponse.keys` is type `NoneType` then select default.

```
if keyDecisionResponse.keys is None:
    keyDecisionResponse.keys = "left" # Or however you assign it
```

Also, make sure that you retain indentation and use proper quotation marks.

Comment: Hi, 

It seems that this works- for now.
Before, I was writing:

if('None' in keyDecisionResponse.keys):
     keyDecisionResponse.keys = "left"

which triggered the same error of NoneType is not iterable.

Thanks!